# How to find url of all Public instances Magnolia CMS

Tags: magnolia

I have a inherit project, with 3 public instances.

I can access the author instance from this url: http://mywebsite.com/author/.magnolia/admincentral

The first public instance from this url:
http://mywebsite.com/.magnolia/admincentral

But I'm not able to login into another public instances. Is there a way to check somewhere in the code, how can I access them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you have the author instance in the same domain than the ONE of the publics instances. So you can acess it like you explain above. Using 2,3,4... public instances you should have one load balancer that can take care of it (if you want same domain for all the public). Otherwise just use diferent domains and you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you very much, I created different domains for each instance.